# Solr long multivalued field is not working

Tags: java, solr, lucene

I have a solr entity with a filed defind as:

```
<field name="rel_ids" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multivalue="true" />
```

and i fill it vie data import handler: with like this

```
<field column="rel_ids" sourceColName="rel_idsc" splitBy=","/>
```

but i can not search on this field for instance the following queries are not working:

rel_ids:1 --> no result

rel_ids:* --> no result

here is my full schema:

```
<schema name="example" version="1.5">
<fields>
    <field name="id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
    <field name="id_S100" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
    <field name="id_S95" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
    <field name="id_S90" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
    <field name="id_None" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" />
    <field name="text" type="text_ar" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="text_noStem" type="text_ar_noStem" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="text_noStem_withHarekat" type="text_ar_noStem_withHarekat" indexed="true" stored="true" />

    <field name="source_book" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="source_volume" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="source_page" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <field name="rel_ids" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<copyField source="text" dest="text_noStem" />
<copyField source="text" dest="text_noStem_withHarekat" />

 <types>
<!-- field type definitions. The "name" attribute is
   just a label to be used by field definitions.  The "class"
   attribute and any other attributes determine the real
   behavior of the fieldType.
     Class names starting with "solr" refer to java classes in a
   standard package such as org.apache.solr.analysis
-->

<!-- The StrField type is not analyzed, but indexed/stored verbatim. -->
<fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true" />

<!-- boolean type: "true" or "false" -->
<fieldType name="boolean" class="solr.BoolField" sortMissingLast="true"/>

<!-- sortMissingLast and sortMissingFirst attributes are optional attributes are
     currently supported on types that are sorted internally as strings
     and on numeric types.
     This includes "string","boolean", and, as of 3.5 (and 4.x),
     int, float, long, date, double, including the "Trie" variants.
   - If sortMissingLast="true", then a sort on this field will cause documents
     without the field to come after documents with the field,
     regardless of the requested sort order (asc or desc).
   - If sortMissingFirst="true", then a sort on this field will cause documents
     without the field to come before documents with the field,
     regardless of the requested sort order.
   - If sortMissingLast="false" and sortMissingFirst="false" (the default),
     then default lucene sorting will be used which places docs without the
     field first in an ascending sort and last in a descending sort.
-->    

<!--
  Default numeric field types. For faster range queries, consider the tint/tfloat/tlong/tdouble types.
-->
<fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
...
```

and

my data import handler field matching:

```
   <dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadithtest" user="root" password="root"/>
<document name="Hadiths" >
<entity name="hadith" transformer="RegexTransformer"  query="SELECT ..." >
    <field name="id" column="id" />
    <field name="text" column="basetext" />
    <field name="source_book" column="source_bookglossary" />
    <field name="source_volume" column="source_volumestring" />
    <field name="source_page" column="source_pagestring" />
    <field name="id_None" column="id_None" />
    <field name="id_S100" column="id_S100" />
    <field name="id_S95" column="id_S95" />
    <field name="id_S90" column="id_S90" />
    <field column="aye_ids" sourceColName="aye_idsc" splitBy="\s+"/>
    <field name="aye_ids_text" column="aye_idsc" />
   <!--
    <field name="TextID" column="text_id" />
    <entity name="RText" query="select * from richtext where richtext.id='${hadith.TextID}'" >
        <field name="Text" column="text" />
    </entry>
    -->
</entity>
```

can anyone help about this problem?
(i cant query on rel_ids

Comment: can you confirm on the sourceColName? at one place it "rel_idsc" and other  as "aye_idsc"? Whats the name in your data-config and schema.xml?

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti thanks i fixed that.

Comment: but does that solve your issue? did you get any value when you search for "*:*"...I mean in the search "*:*" do you get any value for the rel_ids

Comment: no not yet any result and also when i search for \*:\* there is no sign of the field : rel_ids. look like it's empty. but the sql query is contains it!!

Comment: check if below link gives you any hint http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20253103/solr-inconsistencies-using-splitby-to-populate-a-multi-valued-field  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14512055/splitting-database-column-into-multivalued-solr-field

Comment: Can you fix the typo and try? `multivalue="true"` should be `multiValued="true"`

Comment: @arun thanks. I fixed that but the problem still exist.

Answer (score 2):

I fount my mistake!

the problem is that I did not specified the `transformer` in dataImport `entity` tag.

so data import should be like this:

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadithtest" user="root" password="root"/>
<document name="Hadiths" >
<entity name="hadith" transformer="RegexTransformer"  query="SELECT ..." >
    <field name="id" column="id" />
    <field name="text" column="basetext" />
    <field name="source_book" column="source_bookglossary" />
    <field name="source_volume" column="source_volumestring" />
    <field name="source_page" column="source_pagestring" />
    <field name="id_None" column="id_None" />
    <field name="id_S100" column="id_S100" />
    <field name="id_S95" column="id_S95" />
    <field name="id_S90" column="id_S90" />
    <field column="aye_ids" sourceColName="aye_idsc" splitBy="\s+"/>
    <field name="aye_ids_text" column="aye_idsc" />
   <!--
    <field name="TextID" column="text_id" />
    <entity name="RText" query="select * from richtext where richtext.id='${hadith.TextID}'" >
        <field name="Text" column="text" />
    </entry>
    -->
</entity>
</document>
</dataConfig>
```